# Open MS Office Documents with Google Chrome Web Apps?

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-word

I'd like to be able to edit Word, Excel, and Powerpoint files in Google "Drive" using the Docs, Sheets, and Slides Chrome Apps. I know this is possible on Windows and MAC but has anybody figured out how to accomplish this on Linux/Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have google chrome installed and set up, you need to install the following google docs extension for chrome:

```
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-docs/aohghmighlieiainnegkcijnfilokake
```

Then, in nautilus, right click on a docx or xlsx file, go to properties and choose google-chrome as the default application for these files.

This should do it.

Comment: To be clear: where should the Google Docs icon be, in Chrome or in the Application Chooser from Open With?

Comment: It should be available in the dash if you type google.

Comment: It does show in dash, however when opening a file it only opens the Google Docs app but doesn't open the file.

Comment: See my modified answer, hope it helps.